# Replacing div content after submiting contact form 7

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a problem with my contact form. I need my contact form div change it content after clicking submit in my form. I tried to find solution but without success. I have 2 div elements:

1. div1 is form with input fields, acceptance and submit button - this div is visible at start
2. div2 with just some text to thanks for filling the form - this should be hide until the submit is done.

So I want div1 to be hidden after submit and div2 to show.

```
<div class="form padtop25 div1">
    <form id="myFormId" action="yourFormAction" method="post">
        <p class="headline"><?php echo('Lorem Ipsum')?> </p>
        <label for="headline"></label>
        <input type="text" id="headline" name="headline" required>

        <p class="subhead"><?php echo('Lorem Ipsum')?></p>
        <label for="subhead"></label>
        <input type="text" id="subhead" name="subhead" required>

        <p class="subhead"><?php echo('Lorem Ipsum')?></p>
        <label for="subhead2"></label>
        <input type="text" id="subhead2" name="subhead2" required>

        <button type="submit" id="submitButton">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <p class="mandatory"><?php echo('*Mandatory')?></p>
</div>

<div class="div2">
    <p class="headline"><?php echo('Thanks for filling form! Lorem Ipsum')?> </p>
    <p class="subhead"><?php echo('Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum')?></p>
    <p class="subhead"><?php echo('Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum :) Lorem Ipsum AXCV')?></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You can drop the formalities; we appreciate when people are direct here. You said you looked for a solution, but you haven't explained to us what your problem is. What did you try, how did the results differ from your expectations, were there any error messages? We can help you solve a problem, but we can't guess what you want. Furthermore, you tagged your question javascript but only put a couple lines of PHP that don't seem relevant.

Comment: Thank you for anserw, it's my first post here and i'm still learning, next time i will do it as you say.

Comment: No worries, we were all new here at some point. You can also edit your question to provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript for this. Here is an example using simple HTML and JavaScript:

```html
<div class="form padtop25 div1">
    <form id="myFormId" action="customAction" method="post">
        <div>
            <label for="name">Name: *</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
            <br>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="email">Email: *</label><br>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
            <br>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" id="submitButton">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <p class="mandatory">*Mandatory</p>
</div>
<div class="div2" style="display:none;">
    <p class="headline">Thanks for filling form! Lorem Ipsum</p>
</div>

<script>
    document.getElementById('myFormId').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        document.querySelector('.div1').style.display = 'none';
        document.querySelector('.div2').style.display = 'block';
    });
</script>
```